# Flash in IE and Mozilla for asp.net page with master page and content page

Tags: asp.net, flash, master-pages

I have a master page and a child page and have placed the javascript code inside the child page for flash movie.

The problem is the movie seems working when there is a alert on, without at least one alert msg, the code does not work, I am sure you people can solve, I can see that the following code works well in both Mozilla and IE, but only if the alert is ON, if I put it off, then the code does not work. Can anybody tell me what is the workaround :

```
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
 alert(''); // if I remove this , code does not work!!!!!!
 if (window.document[movieName]) 
  {
      return window.document[movieName];
  }
  if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
  {
    if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
      return document.embeds[movieName]; 
  }
  else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
  {
    return document.getElementById(movieName);
  }         
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a short timer where your alert code is.  Have this timer sleep just a little so the window.document can be ready for you to load the movie.  But this is a slight hack.

You can also load the flash in jQuery's $document.ready() to take care of your issue; which would probably give you better results and it is definitely better from the coding aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution, 
in case anybody runs into the sane problem, here is the answer:

just pass the function in the `window.onload` event

```
window.onload = view_gallery;

function view_gallery() {
            var x = document.getElementById('hiddenfield').value;    
            getFlashMovie("galleryfinal").sendTextToFlash(x);

        }

function getFlashMovie(movieName) {

 if (window.document[movieName]) 
  {
      return window.document[movieName];
  }
  if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
  {
    if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
      return document.embeds[movieName]; 
  }
  else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
  {
    return document.getElementById(movieName);
  }

}
```

thanks
arunendra